# Formally prove that there exists a permutation between two partitions of a set having same cardinality?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing

Let $D = \{d_1,...,d_n\}$, let $\mathrm{D_{\mathbf{k}}}$ and $\mathrm{D'_{\mathbf{k}}}$ be partitions on the set such that, it has $\mathrm{k}$ partitions and each partition has a size $k_i$ and $\mathbf{k} = (k_1,..,k_i,...,k_{\mathrm{k}})$.

How can I prove that there exists a permutation $\pi:D \rightarrow D$ such that $$\pi(\mathrm{D'_{\mathbf{k}}}) = \mathrm{D_{\mathbf{k}}}$$
Where $\pi(\mathrm{D'_{\mathbf{k}}})$ is the partition obtained by applying permutation $\pi $ on each constant in D.

---

Now the question sounds convoluted, but it simply asks to prove the following property:

$D =\{1,2,3\} $ , $D_{(1,2)} = \{\{1\}\{2,3\}\}$ and
$D'_{(1,2)} = \{\{2\}\{1,3\}\}$.

Now, obviously there is $\pi_{(2,1,3)}$ such that

$$ \pi_{(2,1,3)}(D'_{(1,2)}) = D_{(1,2)}$$

But how do I prove such an obvious property ?

Comment: I suppose you could prove this by induction, but it would be a pain and not really illuminating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I’m understanding correctly, $D$ might as well be $[n]$. Suppose that your partitions have $m$ parts of sizes $k_1,\ldots,k_m$, say $\{i_{11},\ldots,i_{1k_1}\},\ldots\{i_{m1},\ldots,i_{mk_m}\}$ and $\{j_{11},\ldots,j_{1k_1}\},\ldots\{j_{m1},\ldots,j_{mk_m}\}$, where (just to be definite) each part is listed in increasing order. Then the permutation

$$\begin{pmatrix}
i_{11}&\ldots&i_{ik_1}&i_{21}&\ldots&i_{2k_2}&\ldots&i_{m1}&\ldots&i_{mk_m}\\
j_{11}&\ldots&j_{ik_1}&j_{21}&\ldots&j_{2k_2}&\ldots&j_{m1}&\ldots&j_{mk_m}
\end{pmatrix}$$

would seem to do what you want.